# Having issues with using mysql SELECT in a function

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Started learning mySQL and got stuck on why this command is not working.  I had success with UPDATE commands and SELECT * outside the function so I am guess I am making a mistake in calling the function or perhaps the %s needs to be different...  My google foo did not find anything so I hope you all can help me!

Thank you so much for looking!

CODE:

```
def CheckBalance(UserName, BetAmount): #checks to make sure they can afford the bet.  Returns 0 for no 1 for yes
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='Password',
                      host='127.0.0.1',
                      database='crapsdatabase')
c = cnx.cursor()

BankRoll = c.execute("SELECT PlayerBank FROM player WHERE PlayerName = %s", UserName)

if(BankRoll < BetAmount) or (BetAmount < 0):
    c.close()
    return 0
if(BankRoll >= BetAmount):
    c.close()
    return 1
```

From our main program I import the UpdateDatabase and call it

```
from plugins.database.UpdateDatabase import UpdateBets

a = UpdateBets.CheckBalance("bob", 100)

print(a)
```

This gives the following error:

```
C:\python\python.exe C:/Users/Ray/Desktop/bot/plugins/CRAPS/CrapsUpdated.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ray/Desktop/bot/plugins/CRAPS/CrapsUpdated.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = UpdateBets.CheckBalance("bob", 100)

  File "C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\bot\plugins\database\UpdateDatabase.py", line 16, in CheckBalance
    BankRoll = c.execute("SELECT PlayerBank FROM player WHERE PlayerName = %s", UserName)

  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 515, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))

  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape string literal in the query with apostrophes, so it should be like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT PlayerBank FROM player WHERE PlayerName = '%s'", UserName)
```

Comment: That seemed to fix it... can you tell me what the escape does to the program?  I didnt have to use it in other queries....

Comment: It tells MySQL parser that it is a string literal, not a column name or integer value. I would suggest you reading more about SQL language, particularly about MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/language-structure.html).